# Python loop for :1/30 + 2/29 + 3/28

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, fractions

Hello everyone I have a noob question.

how do I set up the following code to print:

`1/30 + 2/29 + 3/28..........30/1`

The numerator is increasing \ denominator decreasing

I have the following:

```
for i in range(1,31):
    v = i
for j in range(30,0,-1):
    t = j
    print(v/t)
```

but prints

```
1.0
1.0344827586206897
1.0714285714285714
1.1111111111111112
1.15384615384.........
```

how do I get `1/30 + 2/29 + 3/28.....`

Thank you for your help and guidance.

Comment: [What every programmer/CS Major should know about floating-point numbers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) will be *invaluable* to understanding why this prints what it does.

Comment: You don't specify: 1) Do you want to print the actual text "1/30 + 2/29 + 3/28 + ..."? 2) Do you want the exact answer expressed as a fraction? 3) Do you have to calculate it as you're doing it above? ...

Comment: @John Sorry need the actual  text: `1/30 + 2/29 + 3/28...`

Comment: Aha!  A different problem entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you want the strings instead of the numerical values, correct?

```
s = ''
for j in range(30, 0, -1):
    s += "{}/{} + ".format(31-j, j)
print s[:-2]
```

Read [this documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) to get a grasp of it.  Essentially, it's formatting the string, using the two pairs of curly braces as placeholders, and passing in the value 31-j in the first slot, and j in the second.

Surely there is a more elegant way to do it, but this is the quick and dirty method.

Comment: You are right formatting is one of my weakest strong points. The doc was a good read!

Answer (score 3):

You only need one loop! The denominator is always 31 minus the numerator.

```
r = 0
for i in range(1,31):
    r += i / (31 - i)
print(r)
```

Comment: I dont think this is what he wants .... I think he wants the string ,,, not to eval it

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to evaluate the sum and not the string. My bad.

Comment: This has the same problem as the original poster; but +1 for recognizing the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that your numbers are being evaluated to a floating-point number before being printed. Since you want to print them without evaluating, you should be inserting them into a string. The following line demonstrates how to insert variables into the output without evaluating them:

```
print "%d/%d" % (v,t)
```

See http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesseq-strings.html for information about how to format strings for the print function.

However, this still puts each result on a separate line, because the print function automatically inserts a new line. You could build a string with the following loop (notice how you can neatly pack it into one loop rather than two because you can get the denominator by subtracting):

```
string = ''
for i in range(1,31):
    string += "{}/{} + ".format(i, 31-i)
print string
```

and this will give you "1/30 + 2/29 + ... + 30/1 + ", but this still includes the last plus sign and surrounding spaces. To fix that, change the last line to

```
print string[:-3]
```

which removes those last characters.

See http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings for information about how to use the format function.

Comment: Since the division was real division and not integer division, it's safe to assume that this is Python 3.  In Python 3, [`%` as a formatter is deprecated.](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#changes-already-present-in-python-2-6)

Comment: Im pretty sure I heard they reversed this decision due to public outcry :P

Comment: @JoranBeasley yup - the deprecation has gone the way of the dodo

Comment: ahh good I was starting to think i was going crazy while looking for some citation of that

Answer (score 1):

```
print (" + ".join(["%s/%s"%(num,denom)for num,denom in zip(range(1,31),range(30,0,-1))]))
```

I think at least

zipping together `(1,2,3...,30)` and `(30,29,28...,1)` results in a new tuple `((1,30),(2,29),...,(30,1))`

you then iterate over this putting each numerator and denominator into a string resulting in a list like , we do this with format strings `"%s/%s"%numerator,denominator` , although it would be better form to use `"%d/%d"` instead but thats another story

`["1/30","2/29",...,"30/1"]`

then you simply join this list using `' + '` as the glue

Comment: Might be a bit too much for the guy to digest; explaining the code further would get you my +1

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but you can do it with just a single loop.  Each time through the loop, the denominator is just 31 minus the numerator:

```
from fraction import Fraction
for num in range(1,31):
    den = 31 - num
    fraction_string = "%d/%d" % (num, den)
    fraction_value = Fraction(num, den)
    quotient = num / den
    #... do stuff with whichever of the above you want
```

When you're building a result - either adding to a sum, or appending to a string, or outputting something on every iteration - you can do that more succinctly with list comprehensions and list functions.  For example, instead of something like this:

```
quotientList = []
for n in range(1,31):        
    quotientList.append( n / (31 - n) )
```

You can just do this:

```
quotientList = [ n / (31 - n) for n in range(1,31) ]
```

And instead of this:

```
total = 0
for n in someList:
   total = total + n
```

You can just do this:

```
 total = sum(someList)
```

Putting those concepts together, here are three possibilities I see for what you're trying to do:

1. Print out the literal string `1/30 + 2/29 + 3/28 +`...`+30/1`:

   `print( " + ".join( "%d/%d" % (n, 31-n) for n in range(1,31) ) )`
2. Evaluate that as an arithmetic expression and print the result:

   `print( sum( n/(31.0-n) for n in range(1,31) ) )`
3. ... but as a fraction instead of a decimal:

   `from fractions import Fraction`
   ...
   `print( sum( Fraction(n,31-n) for n in range(1,31) ) )`